# Selenium "new firefoxdriver()" throwns KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, selenium, webdriver

Help - I'm a newbie to Selenium Webdriver. I have installed selenium weddriver onto VS 2015.

When I try and run

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

I always get a

> system.collections.generic.KeyNotFoundException "key not found in dictionary".

I know I need a webdriver.json file and here is mine:

```
{
    "capabilities":
    [
        {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "version": "48.0.2",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "maxInstances": 1
         },
        {
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "version": "11",
        "platform": "WINDOWS",
        "maxInstances": 1
        }
    ],
    "configuration":
    {
    "nodeTimeout":120,
    "port":5555,
    "hubPort":4444,
    "hubHost":"localhost",
    "nodePolling":2000,
    "registerCycle":10000,
    "register":true,
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "maxSession":1,
    }
}
```

I have two main problems:
1) I have no idea which key is missing
2) I have tried searching for documentation and examples of this json file without luck.

My Selenium installation, references and using statements all appear to confirm to the installation instructions.

```
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile.ReadDefaultPreferences()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxProfile..ctor(String profileDirectory,       Boolean deleteSourceOnClean)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver.CreateExtensionConnection(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver..ctor(FirefoxBinary binary, FirefoxProfile profile)
at WebTest.BasicCalculatorSteps.GivenThatTheSimpleCalulatorIsOpen() in C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\hf_regulator_emulator_BDD\WebTest\BasicCalculatorSteps.cs:line 18
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(StepInstance stepInstance)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
at WebTest.BasicCalculatorFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
at WebTest.BasicCalculatorFeature.ShowThatAdditionWorks_() in C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\hf_regulator_emulator_BDD\WebTest\BasicCalculator.feature:line 15
Result Message: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

Comment: Thanks Kirtil for cleaning up my submission

Comment: Here is my stack trace..

Comment: There is an extra "," after maxsession: '  "maxSession":1,  } '